# Running .jar in Java

Tags: java, exception, jar

I want to run a `.jar` file in Java, but I get an exception and it doesn't work. In the directory **C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/apache-solr-4.0.0/example**, I have a file called **start.jar**.
My last example this, but it throws an exception. What do I have to do in order to fix it?

```
public void runStart()  {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\apache-solr-4.0.0\\example\\start.jar");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SolrForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error? Post stacktrace..

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\apache-solr-4.0.0\example\start.jar": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)

Comment: you should run it as a java app not as an .exe

Answer (score 3):

You need to exec with `java -jar` in the command line, otherwise you're not really executing anything.

e.g. `rt.exec("java -jar myjar.jar");`

Oh, *and* you'll need to wait for the process to finish; otherwise it may get terminated unexpectedly when it drops out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to run that command in a console, that doesn't work as well. A jar file is not an executable by itself, but it can be executed by Java.

Try to do it like this:

```
public void runStart()  {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("java -jar C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\apache-solr-4.0.0\\example\\start.jar");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SolrForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This way you start Java, saying that you give it a jar. If Java is in your path (or in the current directory), it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing only a file, that is note an executable application. Assuming that your Java enviroment is configured, you should change your line to this:

```
Process p = rt.exec("java - jar C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\apache-solr-4.0.0\\example\\start.jar");
```

Comment: If it didn't raise an exception it is because the "java" command was found. What can be happening is an exception when you started the application. It is also possible that the jar doesn't exist. I suggest you run this command in the SO and see what happens.

Comment: i use this command for another jar file, again i didn't get exception , but application doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
rt.exec("c:\\java_path\\bin\\java -jar C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\apache-solr-4.0.0\\example\\start.jar");
```

Make sure to replace `c:\\java_path\\bin\\java` with your actual absolute path to the java binary.